# Need help converting a nested SQL statement to LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a statement similar to this that I need to run in Linq. I started down the road of using .Contains, and can get the first tier to work, but cannot seem to grasp what I need to do to get additional tiers.

Here's the SQL statement:

```
select * 
from aTable
where aTableId in
    (select aTableId from bTable
    where bTableId in 
        (select bTableId from cTable
        where cTableId in
            (select cTableId from dTable
            where dField = 'a guid'
            )
        )
    )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the simplest translation would be:

```
var query = from a in aTable
            where (from b in bTable
                   where (from c in cTable
                          where (from d in dTable
                                 where dField == "a guid"
                                 select d.cTableId)
                                .Contains(c.cTableId)
                          select c.bTableId)
                         .Contains(b.bTableId)
                   select b.aTableId)
                   .Contains(a.aTableId)
            select a;
```

However, it's likely that a join would be significantly simpler:

```
var query = from a in aTable
            join b in bTable on a.aTableId equals b.aTableId
            join c in cTable on b.bTableId equals c.bTableId
            join d in dTable on c.cTableId equals d.cTableId
            where d.dField == "a guid"
            select a;
```

I haven't checked, but I *think* they'll do the same thing...

Comment: That's what i needed. The only addition was to define the type in the .Contains statements.

ie: .Contains((Guid) a.aTableId)

Comment: and yes, although the SQL is different for both of these options, the Execution Plan is identical. The second option using Joins is a much more readable solution.